# Is there a way to automatically install the relevant package when opening an unknown file type?

Tags: package-repositories

Is there an automated way to discover “well-known” packages related to a given file type, *e.g.* `scala-mode2` for Scala files, `rust-mode` for Rust files, etc., and install them automatically when opening a file of that type for the first time?

If several packages apply, the user could be prompted with a list of choices that she can then choose from if she so desires.

Answer (score 5):

[Emacs Prelude](https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude) does this. The [relevant macro](https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude/blob/master/core/prelude-packages.el#L121):

```
(defmacro prelude-auto-install (extension package mode)
  "When file with EXTENSION is opened triggers auto-install of PACKAGE.
PACKAGE is installed only if not already present.  The file is opened in MODE."
  `(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist
                `(,extension . (lambda ()
                                 (unless (package-installed-p ',package)
                                   (package-install ',package))
                                 (,mode)))))
```

Comment: It hardcodes the list of packages associated with file types AFAICT; is that the only way?

Comment: The other way I could think of would be to do a catch-all in `auto-mode-alist` (like `"\..*\'"`) and bind it to some function that does what you want. But I'm not really sure how useful that would be unless it actually knows which is the relevant mode for the relevant file type (in which case you're back to hard-coding).

Comment: You arespecifying the packages that *you* want to be installed to open the file using the function/mode *you* want. That necessarily means "hard-coding", no? You could easily change the code to allow for a list of packages to be installed together, or a list of packages that Emacs should try to install, in order, until one of them succeeds so that its function/mode can be used. Beyond that, what kind of "soft-coding" are you imagining? Do you want Emacs to *guess* what package and function you want used? If so, guess based on what?  + see @shosti's comment about runtime pkg/mode determination.

Comment: @Drew I expect package authors to know what they wrote their package for, and I expect ELPA to offer some discovery facility to enquire what a package was written for. I don’t think this is unreasonable.  What I mean is that ELPA should support this, not be hard-coded by a third-party library.

Comment: In that case, please send your enhancement request to Emacs Dev: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: @SébastienLeCallonnec Also you should be aware that the Emacs core devs have a strict policy against any reference to non-GNU packages (i.e. everything in MELPA and Marmalade), so even if it got into core Emacs it would most likely be limited to GNU ELPA packages.